# Vanilla JavaScript: How to search an array of objects , key is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have aan array of objects.
Each object is `{key, value}`
For each object key is an array consisting of strings `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.
I want to remove any duplicates of `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` from the array so that further processing is only done on unique values.

Currently I'm doing this

```
function removeArrayDupes(input){
var i = input.length;
var previous;
input.sort();

 if (i){
        while (--i){
            var cur = input[i];
            if (!cur.key){
                // Remove empty records
                input.splice(i,1);
            } else {
                // Clear duplicates
                if ((previous) && (input[i].key) === previous){
                    input.splice(i,1);
                    regex= "/" + JSON.stringify(input[i].key) + "/g";
                    previous = input[i].key;
                } else {
                    previous = input[i].key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem: If dupes < 3, the single duplicate is not removed.

My brain is tired because I can't see where I'm screwing this up.

I could use an extra brain or two to resolve this.

I looking for solutions usinng Vanilla JavaScript. It's not just about making it work<
I want to gain comprehension on the problem and if there is a better algorith.

TIA

Sample data:

```
[
{key: ["foo","bar","baz"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["foo","bar","baz"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["foo","bar","baz"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["baz","bar","foo"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["bar","foo","baz"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["bar","foo","bar"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["bar","foo","bar"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["bar","foo","bar"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["bar","foo","bar"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["baz","bar","foo"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["baz","bar","foo"], value: "Some data"},
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
{key: ["foo","bar","baz"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["baz","bar","foo"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["bar","foo","baz"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["bar","foo","bar"], value: "Some data"},
{key: ["baz","bar","foo"], value: "Some data"}
]
```

Comment: could you add a sample of data, and the expected result?